# PHPMailer and specific characters in subject (UTF-8?)

Tags: phpmailer

I'm trying to send email with PHPMailer. Everythings work except UTF-8 encoding in Subject.
I still get html code (commancé and has to be "commancé") in my mail client.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';

try {
    //Server settings

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('kevin@expl.com', 'Kevin de Exple');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Add a recipient
    
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $subject = 'RE: La plantation de votre arbre a commanc&eacute;';
    $sub = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
    $mail->Subject = $sub;

...
```

Could you help me? I tried everything on the web :)

Have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do things the hard way! The first step is setting the `CharSet` property to `UTF-8`, which you've done. For the subject, you have this:

```
$subject = 'RE: La plantation de votre arbre a commanc&eacute;';
$sub = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
$mail->Subject = $sub;
```

There's a lot of unnecessary stuff going on in there. All you need to do is:

```
$mail->Subject = 'RE: La plantation de votre arbre a commancé';
```

PHPMailer takes care of all the encoding for you. The only thing to be careful of here is to be sure that you are actually working in UTF-8 in your editor. If you're using ISO-8859-1 or similar, it won't work – though it will look identical in your code.

As for spelling mistakes, I'm going to have to leave them up to you...

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
    function correct_encoding($text) {
      $current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, 'auto');
      $text = iconv($current_encoding, 'UTF-8', $text);
      return $text;
    }
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';///<-- use lowercase
    //$mail->Encoding = 'base64';//usually it is not necessary

try {
    //Server settings

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('kevin@expl.com', 'Kevin de Exple');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Add a recipient
    
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $subject = 'RE: La plantation de votre arbre a commanc&eacute;';
    //$sub = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
    $mail->Subject = correct_encoding($subject);
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you but it doesn't work. I still have commanc&eacute; :)